# how to store and validate qr code in server using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, qr-code

We are implementing a mobile app using the following technologies:

- Node.JS & express
- MongoDB & mongoose
- Flutter

Suppose we should generate QR Code with the goods information like name, price, expiration date and etc. which should be unique and whenever customer scan the QR Code it should be validated by connecting to the server, fetching data and add the selected good to cart.

As I have searched on the internet, I found that we should convert the data to canvas (to have QR Code). Is there any solution to generate QR code in server side, store and validate it in mongodb?

Here is our product.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({
    productID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    expirationDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    discount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        trim: true
    },
    producer: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    QRCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: [THIS](https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode) Module maybe help you

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH The problem is that I want implement everything on the server.

Comment: This works on server also. read their 1st point of Highlights

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH Would you please add it as an answer post?

Answer (score 2):

```
use jsqr,jimp we can decode the qr image and we will get data after that one we will compare the db and decoder data....
        ==========================================================================
        npm i jimp, jsqr 
        const Jimp = require('jimp');
        const jsQR = require("jsqr"); 
        Jimp.read('./path/to/image.jpg')// image path use path.join(__dirname,'/fileName')
          .then(image => {
            const code = jsQR(image.bitmap.data,image.bitmap.width,image.bitmap.height);

            if (code) {
          console.log("Found QR code", code);
    //comapre db data and code
        }

          })
          .catch(err => {
            // Handle an exception.
          });
```